# CUDA __device__ of type struct

Tags: cuda

CUDA experts, if I have defined in the host code a new type:

```
struct float_3{
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
};
```

and I have transferred some data of this type to the device, can I create `__device__` calls of that new type,i.e:

```
__device__ float_3 foo(float_3 r,float b,int a){
}
```

Can we create `__device__` of any type? Or just `int`,`float`,`dlouble`,`void`, etc...
And is it possible to return a pointer on __device__? i.e 
`__device__ float_3* foo(){}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can create `__device__` of any type. It is just a qualifier that makes that function compile for running on the device and be callable from the device.

And by the way, CUDA has a `float3` type. I have never used it but if I recall correctly it provides the same functionality of your `float_3` and also comes with a constructor.

Comment: The CUDA float3 type also has correct alignment declaration, another advantage.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we create 
>   `__device__`of any type?

The short answer is *yes*. The long answer is, yes, if it is a user-defined type as your `float_3`, you can define a `__device__` variable pointer and allocate memory in device using `cudaMalloc`.

> is it possible to return a pointer on
>   device?

Yes,  you can do it.